# Drop a local temporary table within a function in MonetDB

Tags: sql, function, temp-tables, monetdb

Consider the following scenario.  I have a bunch of user defined functions, `f_i`, that create, populate, and use a local temporary table with the same name `res`:

```
create function f_i()
returns table( … )
begin
       # Result stats table.
       create local temporary table res(
             param1 int,
             param2 int
       );

       /* Populate res */
       /* Use res in some queries */

       return table(
             /* Query involving res */
       );
end;
```

My first question is: `Does create local temporary table x` create a table that is disposed/dropped as soon as the function where it was declared finishes execution?  I assumed this was the case, but I’m now skeptical as we are running into all sorts of concurrency issues that point to the `res` table not being cleared out properly from memory.

This takes me to the second question:  How do I drop a temporary table if such table exists?  The reason for this is to prevent `table create` exceptions (which we are currently running into).  I’d like to achieve something along these lines:

```
create function f_i()
returns table( … )
begin
       # Drop local temporary table if such table exists.
       drop local temporary table res;         <-------- How do I do this in MonetDB?

       # Result stats table.
       create local temporary table res(
             param1 int,
             param2 int
       );

       /* Populate res */
       /* Use res in some queries */

       return table(
             /* Query involving res */
       );
end;
```

Where, as you can see, I want to explicitly drop the local temporary table `res` if such exists.  If I leave the `local temporary` markers in the drop statement, MonetDB complains that it found unexpected `LOCAL` or `TEMPORARY` tokens.  I wouldn’t like to remove these markers because a statement like:

```
drop table res;
```

will drop any table in the default function schema with that name.

Any help and hints are well appreciated!

Comment: did you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: @Alam I tried with `drop table tmp.yourTableName` and it works, as long as you don't do it within a user defined function.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I really need to do it in my function\procedure, it doesn't allow it in either of them even though the documentation https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Procedures says that its possible in a procedure, The error says it an "invalid flow control statement".

Comment: @Alam, we faced the same inconvenient limitation

Answer (score 0):

try following?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL   DROP TABLE #Temp;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, MonetDB doesn't have such a function like OBJECT_ID.  There's no information either as where to find local temporary tables created in a user-defined function.  If I could tell where information about local temporary tables is stored, I could query that table and use the homologue to `if` to drop it.  My question remains: is it possible to drop a local temporary table?